# AngularJS + Karma (Testacular) - Unit Test failing

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am attempting to create my first unit test in Karma for an AngularJS based web application. I am using Jasmine as the testing framework.

My unit test looks like:

```
describe('FooBar', function() {

    describe('FBCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl;

        beforeEach(function() {
            scope = {};
            ctrl = new FBCtrl(scope);
        });

        it('should have correct gender values', function() {
            expect(scope.values[0].values).toBe(["M", "F"]);
        });
    });
});
```

Now, when I run the test, I get an error in the following form:

```
Chrome 26.0 (Linux) FooBar FBCtrl should have correct gender values FAILED
Expected [ 'M', 'F' ] to be [ 'M', 'F' ].
Error: Expected [ 'M', 'F' ] to be [ 'M', 'F' ].
        at null.<anonymous> //followed by the js file given has input to Karma
```

The L.H.S of this expectation was a variable defined inside a scope of a controller. As can be seen, the value has been picked up and the comparison also seems to be correct - yet Karma reports this as a failure / error.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is because in javascript expression `['val']===['val']` always evaluates to false. Therefore karma uses the same thing to compare values, and it fails as well. Easiest solution, will be to compare them like this:

```
var values = scope.values[0].values;
expect(values.toString()).toBe(["M", "F"].toString());
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
var values = scope.values[0].values;
expect(values.length).toBe(2);
expect(values).toContain('M');
expect(values).toContain('F');
```

Or if order is important as well:

```
var values = scope.values[0].values;
expect(values.length).toBe(2);
expect(values[0]).toBe('M');
expect(values[1]).toBe('F');
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the matcher `toBe` use `toEqual`

Jasmine's `toBe` uses the === operator in Javascript. `toEqual` uses a custom function which smartly compares arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you might want to change here. shouldn't really nest describes unless you have a good reason. You are incorrectly instantiated your controller in the beforeEach (think DI in angular). Also, you are using "toBe" when you probably mean "toEqual". Try this code:

```
 (function() {
 'use strict';

 describe('MainController', function(){
     var controller;
     var scope;

     beforeEach(module('MY_APP'));
     beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
         scope = {};
         controller = $controller('MainController', {$scope: scope})
     }))

     it('should be defined.', function () {
         expect(controller).toBeDefined();
     });

     it('should have correct gender values.', function() {
         expect(scope.values[0].values).toEqual(["M", "F"]);
     })
})
```